# Is there a way to enable or disable flags of chrome through custom chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am referring `chrome://flags`

What i am curious to know is that whether it is possible to enable or disable a particular flag of chrome through custom chrome extension?

For e.g.- I want to enable `Enable Media Source API on <video> elements.` flag through chrome extension.

Answer (score 0):

You currently cannot change experimental features (chrome://flags) through extensions. If you have a valid scenario, bring it up to the [Chromium-Extensions](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-extensions) mailing list.

Comment: How does it mesh with chromium-extensions / chromium-apps lists being shut down as support channels?

Comment: @Mohamed, There's loads and loads of valid scenarios for this. One listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46712951/632951