# Reading current settings of Chrome via Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there an easy way to **read** the user's current settings?

No modification needed, verily I simply only need harmless read access.

For example

- I need to discover the setting for flag ≪New omnibox answers in suggest types≫
- I need to know the current default search engine (per chrome://settings/searchEngines )

Comment: The only way is to write a separately installed native OS utility that reads the settings and communicates with your extension via nativeMessaging API.

Comment: @wOxxOm, Google [⨕ always](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/blog-kenneth-io/taking_chrome_devtools_outside_of_the_browser_15/#comment-3562525018) maketh things difficult whenever the omnibar is involved. Do you happen to have a hint who might be the VP of Chrome's omnibar monopoly?